# How to initialize a *slog.Logger with a sensible default?

Tags: go, logging

Using the [log/slog](https://pkg.go.dev/log/slog) package (Go 1.21+), what's the best way to initialize a logger when the user has not provided one? For instance:

```golang
type MyServer struct {
    logger *slog.Logger
}

// Optionally set a logger
func (s *MyServer) SetLogger(logger *slog.Logger) {
    s.logger = logger
}

// Default server that doesn't log
func New() *MyServer {
    return &MyServer{ /* what? */ }
}
```

Note it cannot be nil since that would require nil-checks while logging. Some ideas:

1. Implement a no-op handler and initialize to `slog.New(NoopHandler)`.
2. Use `slog.New(slog.NewTextHandler(io.Discard, nil))`. This would suppress logging but still run handler-specific code.
3. Use `slog.Default()`, although it makes me uneasy to enable logging by default, as well as querying a global variable.